# NSString contains : <null> and is crashing my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've an NSString thats populated from some data returned via JSON.

The code works great under normal circumstances but there is an occasion when i get returned  by the JSON.

When i do a check to see if my NSString == nil or == null it fails the test.

But the fact that the NSString contains  crashes my app.

So does  have some special meaning in Objective C? Or should i just do a string compare and see if the string is equal to  rather than being nil and handle it that way.

This has me a little confused.

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: Can you post your relevant code? It might help to see what is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<null>` is what `NSNull` returns for its `-description` method. You need to also check for

```
myString == [NSNull null]
```

in this case.

Additional info: IIRC the common Objective-C JSON stuff will use `[NSNull null]` for `null`s in the JSON structure, to differentiate the value from one that simply isn't there.

Comment: +1. More specifically, collection classes (such as dictionaries and arrays) can't hold nil objects, so `[NSNull null]` is used instead as a placeholder.

Comment: Why do you think this is about `NSNull` and a collection? Neither were mentioned in the post; the OP is talking about `NSString`, and logging an object (string or not) that is `nil` prints `(null)`.

Comment: Because it's not really an NSString!

Comment: Also I've run into this issue before.

Comment: It's *supposed* to be an NSString, sure, but a lot of stuff uses `NSNull` as a placeholder for "null but exists". Also, `(null)` and `<null>` are not the same!

Comment: (Mostly I just wish he'd come back and verify one way or the other.)

Comment: @Josh: It's a good assumption because the string is being returned in JSON.

Comment: Yes, there really needs to be some more interaction from the OP. My point was that the OP didn't say `<null>`, you assumed it; seeing `(null)` is also a possible interpretation of the given information. You're absolutely right that `NSNull` is the "no object" placeholder in collections.

Comment: I didn't assume: the question title specifically says `<null>`.

Comment: Oh, wow. I was only looking at the body. Egg on my face. Comments withdrawn, with my apology.

Answer (score 2):

`NSString *` is just a pointer to a `NSString` object.
To test for null pointer:

```
NSString *str;

if (str) {
    // str points to an object
    if ([str length] == 0) {
        // string is empty
    }
} else
    // str points to nothing
}
```

If you want to check for whitespace, you can trim the NSString with `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`.

Comment: In general, one shouldn't check for nil before calling a method like `length` because `[str length]` will return 0 if `str` is `nil`.

Comment: @Jon Reid: that doesn't make sense. If you just check for length, you will end up assuming you have a valid but empty string object, which is likely to cause problems later.

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if it's null by.

```
if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
   // str is null.
}
```

Comment: This is not how `NSNull` works. This will give you a boolean false, if `str` _is_ `nil`, but that's because you're sending a message to `nil`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
if([string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSLog(@"This is JSON null");
} else {
    NSLog(@"This is a string, do what you wanna do with it");
}
```